# spring boot with vaadin takes several minutes to start

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I know there have been a few posts about it and i tried a few solutions which seemed to have improved the situation a bit, but I still experience an extraordinarily long start-up on my machine.

I use spring-boot 2.4.4 and vaadin 14.3.9 for my frontend developing in STS 4.10 on Windows 10. I compile using Java 11.
Having debug enabled in my properties I can see a huge gap of around 5 minutes between "Mapping servlets" and "Starting Frontend compilation"

```
11:54:30.236 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
11:54:31.171 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
11:54:31.172 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6870 ms
11:54:52.463 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Mapping filters: filterRegistrationBean urls=[/*] order=-2147483647, springSecurityFilterChain urls=[/*] order=-100, characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105, cacheCleanupFilter urls=[/*] order=2147483647, getBasicAuthFilter urls=[/*] order=2147483647, getFormAuthFilter urls=[/*] order=2147483647, loggingFilter urls=[/*] order=2147483647
11:54:52.464 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans - Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/], springServlet urls=[/vaadinServlet/*]
[38;5;35m
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
[0m[94mVaadin application has been deployed and started to the context path "/".
[0m11:59:07.893 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.b.a.m.w.s.WebMvcMetricsFilter - Filter 'webMvcMetricsFilter' configured for use
```

so I have no clue what happens in between. I suppose it could be vaadin doing some of its magic, but I cannot be certain.

I'd love to paste the output for the auto configuration here but unfortunately this would make me exceed the 30k characters limit (Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 122954). Is there a better way to paste it or are there certain parts of it that might be of value for you?

In my application properties (yml) I also whitelisted my views package for vaadin and in my windows hosts file I uncommented the localhost resolution lines, but I'm not certain if that has any influence

```
vaadin:
  whitelisted-packages:
  - xx/path/to/view
```

In addition I just upgraded to the newest STS version (see above), and created a new workspace just to make sure this wasn't the reason.

Not sure where to start looking and how to find out what's exactly happening in those 5 minutes. Maybe you can help me find a solution. thanks in advance

Comment: Around that point the dev-server downloads node deps and runs webpack and whatnot. Can you rule out, that there are not networks problems. Is the second run fast? Is there a node_modules with lots of stuff in it? Is the projekt on a local SSD with a decent filesystem? Do you run this native or with WSL?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot. Are you running the app as WAR in a Tomcat server?

Comment: @cfrick Hi and thx, i have quite a stable network here but the problem occured in multiple networks so far as well as when i'm offline. is there a test i can run to be sure? the second run (simple restart of my spring boot app in sts) has the same problem. there are quite a few entries in node_modules folder (569) but it's loaded by vaadin. i already cleaned my project dir once with no changes. i have an ssd and start the project natively from STS (run as application as well as run as spring boot app). i do have wsl though for docker but i didn't configure it explicitly for debugging in sts

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Hi and thx. I start the spring boot app directly as an application (using Main Method) from sts eclipse, meaning it starts using the embedded tomcat. I do not use a separate tomcat and deploy the war/jar file there

Comment: You could try to debug the application and hit "pause" within the 5 minutes where nothing seems to be happen. Make sure all threads are suspended. Then try to find a suspicious thread by inspecting the stack traces. You could also try to increase log level to TRACE and see if the 5 minutes gap has some logs then.

Comment: Can you build a production build and see if that takes the same time? The prod build does nearly the same (gathers the deps, runs webpack to create some artifacts) minus running a server on localhost for hot-reload. Ruling out, that your machine just is to slow, I'd assume that something is timing out and that might as well just be the node-stuff, that get's started. If you easily can check your IO (net and disk) and your CPU in the gap: if nothing is happening, something is waiting). Also have you tried with a fresh starter project?

Comment: @cfrick i just checked several starter configurations and the plain one as well as a configuration using spring web, security, mysql start up quite fast. when i add vaadin it takes a little longer to start up but nowhere near the 5 to 10 mins i'm currently experiencing. when i do a production build of my project and start it up from the console with native windows java -jar it seems faster (1st start was 2 mins) but it still takes its time. i stopped and restarted the process and it was 200 seconds. still faster but not as quick. i'll check with a newer vaadin version as Tatu Lund suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the older vaadin version had this issue an upgrade didn't solve it for me. the problem was actually there in plain sight and an configuration issue.

Using the yaml format in my properties I configured the white-listing originally like:

```
vaadin:
  whitelisted-packages:
  - xx/path/to/view
```

this format was given to me by eclipse's code completion, but it's wrong, or at least vaadin doesn't accept it this way. the correct format for vaadin would be like:

```
vaadin:
  whitelisted-packages: xx/path/to/view
```

with multiple packages apparently separated by commas.
Now my project starts within a few seconds.

thanks for everyone commenting and helping me to analyze it.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a known](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/571) issue in Vaadin versions prior to 14.4.0. In version 14.4.0 newer the problem should have been fixed.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. i will try to upgrade vaadin. i used to run in vaadin 14.4 for a while but had to downgrade to 14.3.9 because i experienced some session drops in combination with WebComponentExporter (calling vaadin via jsp) or even using vaadin within an iframe. the weird thing is that i have another page in this setting where the session didn't drop but i couldn't find the causing difference between these two. anyways i will try 14.4

Comment: i upgraded to 14.5.1 and it still needs 5 to 10 mins to start. then I removed my logback config, because i had the feeling that the config didn't show me everything, and it showed the following: VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 323 seconds 
is the use of the whitelisted property in my original post correct? according to https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/571 this should be a solution